# How to access and modify a particular value in a cell array in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

How can i access and change a value in a particular cell in matlab...for example in the result of the following code, I want to change the value of the 3rd element of the 2nd cell as indicated in the attached image

```
n=6;
A=cell([1 3]);
A{1,1} = [zeros(1,n)];
A{1,2} = [zeros(1,n)];
A{1,3} = [zeros(1,n)];
```

[image].

Comment: `A{1,2}(1,3)=10` or in this case simply `A{2}(3)=10` will also work since you have only one row

Comment: @Sardar Usama: Thanks....works fine for me.